# If statement in sql query not working in wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, if-statement, where-clause

This is my piece of code and the check_result variable is coming to be 0, when it shouldn't be 0, please help

```
$check_result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $table_name3  WHERE IF('$admin_Name' != '', admin_id = '$admin_ID_result', 1=1) AND
                                        IF('$client_Name' != '', client_id = '$client_ID_result', 1=1) AND IF('$date' != '' && '$date2' == '', DATE(time) BETWEEN '$date1' AND #12/31/2050#, 1=1)
                                        AND IF('$date2' != '' && '$date' == '', DATE(time) BETWEEN #12/31/2000# AND '$date2', 1=1)
                                        AND IF('$date' != '' && '$date2' != '', DATE(time) BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2', 1=1)");
```

This is the html

```
$admin_Name = $_POST['admin_Name'];
   $client_Name = $_POST['client_Name']; 
   $admin_ID_result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $users_table WHERE user_email = '$admin_Name' ");
   $client_ID_result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $users_table WHERE user_email = '$client_Name' ");
   $date = $_POST['date'];
   $date2 = $_POST['date2'];

echo "<form method='post' action='" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "'>
         Admin Email: <br/><input type='text' name='admin_Name' maxlength='100'>
                      <br/><br/>
         Client Email:<br/><input type='text' name='client_Name' max='100'>
                      <br/><br/>
         Date From:   <input type='date' name='date' min='1990-12-31' max='2050-12-31'>
         Date To:     <input type='date' name='date2' min='1990-12-31' max='2050-12-31'>
                      <br/><br/>
                      <input type='submit' name='Submit'>
      </form>";
```

Comment: Are you getting an invalid SQL error?

Comment: @Anand No, the plugin works, but when I display the check_result variable, it comes to be 0, but it is not actually 0.

Comment: you can write query without if statement

Comment: @ Pankaj katiyar I want the query to be valid even if only one field is filled out and I want to shortlist the results as user fills in more fields, how can I achieve this without if statements ?